# Can Google's Speech-to-Text API return the correlation between speech and text?

Tags: google-api, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, subtitle, google-speech-api

I am working on an application that requires knowing which portions (timings) of the speech signal correspond to which portions (words) of converted text. Does anyone know if this is possible using Google's Speech-to-Text API?

Answer (score 0):

There are different libraries for that, for example [Gentle](https://github.com/lowerquality/gentle)